# Microsoft Edge remembers the last used keyboard layout

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, microsoft-edge, windows-11-v23h2

I have the latest Windows 11 Pro 23H2 with several keyboard layouts installed in it. My default input language is English, the other advanced keyboard settings are the followings:

[image: Advanced keyboard settings]

Since some time the built-in Microsoft Edge browser started to remember the last selected keyboard layout and restore it the next time the program is opened. I expect that the default language should be English and start typing thinking I am doing this in English, but you can feel my irritation when, after typing a phrase, I see it typed in a different keyboard layout.

This happens only in Edge. Other apps work as expected. I couldn't find any setting in Edge or in Windows that could help to turn off this strange behavior. Does anybody know how to turn this off?

Comment: @John, did you mean the 'Preferred languages' section? Yes, English is stated everywhere as the first language.

Comment: @John, can you reproduce this behavior on your pc? I even did a clean install of Windows, but the result is the same. BTW, IIRC, I experienced this behavior also in Windows 11 22H2 I had before the upgrade.

Comment: @John, just add 1 or 2 additional languages to your OS. You can then remove them easily.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and let me know if something was found.

Comment: @harrymc, I can't understand how this could help because I had the same problem earlier in 22H2. However I launched `DISM /CheckHealth` and `sfc /scannow`. The former found nothing, the latter found and fixed some problems. But this did not help to solve my problem with Edge. It seems, it is a planned improvement from Microsoft we can't turn off. Can you reproduce this problem in your copy of the OS?

Comment: SFC is good in locating problems, but less so in correcting them. To bring Windows to a known coherent state [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all Edge Extensions, or do a Edge settings reset (which effectively does disable all extensions. In my case I had installed some virtual keyboard extensions that were causing that problem.

Comment: Nothing helped, but the idea as to the root of the problem is pretty interesting.